# How to find records with date next week in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model with a `datetime` column for projected delivery dates and want to pull records of the orders that will be delivered next week. Anyone know the best way to show this?

```
model Orders

created_at, datetime
modified_at, datetime
deliver_at, datetime # stores a future date when the package will be delievered
```

I'm trying to get all the items with `deliver_at` projected for next week.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer this method, as it avoids unnecessary SQL:

```
Order.where(:deliver_at => Time.now.next_week..Time.now.next_week.end_of_week)
```

This would find all orders where the `deliver_at` date is between the beginning of next Monday and the end of the following Sunday.

I recommend checking out the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for the ActiveRecord Query Interface. This method is described in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Order.where("deliver_at > ? AND deliver_at < ?", Time.now.next_week, Time.now.next_week.end_of_week)
```